# add_filter function in the theme (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, themes, url-rewriting, add-filter

I have a function for encrypt the content:

```
function rewrite_text( $article, $case_sensitive=false ) {

    $workwith=$article;
    *(hide line code for copyright)....(hide line code for copyright)*
    $codul='<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(String.fromCharCode('.$numbers.'));
</script>';
        $workwith=$codul;
        }
    return $workwith;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'rewrite_text', 100);
```

In my wordpress theme (deTube wordpress theme) have a function for show youtube player (in theme_name/functions.php):

```
function dp_video($post_id, $autoplay = false) {    
    $file = get_post_meta($post_id, 'dp_video_file', true);
    $file = !empty($file) ? explode("\n", $file) : array();
    $url = trim(get_post_meta($post_id, 'dp_video_url', true));
    $code = trim(get_post_meta($post_id, 'dp_video_code', true));
    if(!empty($code)) {
        $code = do_shortcode($code);
        if(function_exists('jwplayer_tag_callback'))
            $code = jwplayer_tag_callback($code);
        $code = extend_video_html($code, $autoplay);        
        echo '<div class="video-wrap">'.$code.'</div>';
    } elseif(!empty($url)) {
        $youtube_id = getYouTubeIdFromURL($url);
        $video = "<div class=\"video-wrap\"><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/".$youtube_id."?modestbranding=1&version=3&hl=vi_VN&rel=0&autoplay=1&showsearch=0&iv_load_policy=3&theme=light\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowFullScreen=\"true\" allowScriptAccess=\"always\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/></div>";
        echo $video;
```

I want to encrypt youtube link (youtube player code) by add_filter function dp_video, using:

```
add_filter('dp_video', 'rewrite_text', 100);
```

But it's not working!
Can you help me add filter for dp_video function?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `add_filter('dp_video')` there must be an `apply_filters('dp_video')` somewhere. If you wanna filter $video for example you can change the last line to

```
echo apply_filters('dp_video', $video);
```